# How to upload videos to laravel storage via react?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

So it's quite easy to find ways on how to upload images to laravel storage via react axios, but I keep struggling to find a way on videos upload. So heres what I'd like to know:

1) how should my jsx form look like?
2) how should my axios request look like?
3) how should my controller's function look like?

Also, I know that in order to upload multiple files one should have a little more complex logic happening so I'd like to have 2 examples:
 1st on how to upload multiple videos at once
 2nd on how to upload one video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload videos with the [FileReader Javascript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), which can be used inside your ReactJS component, then in Laravel is almost the same as you save images ([Laravel File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem)).

1. Your jsx just need to have some input file with multiple attribute enabled

`<input type="file" name="the-name" onChange={this.handleInputChange } multiple>`

Then with a function you can get an array of files, in this case videos. After read all videos, you can add it to a react state variable.

```
// ...React component

handleInputChange = (e)=>{

    // e.target.files is an array of files
    let videos = [];

    // Read each video from the input
    e.target.files.forEach((file, index)=>{
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = ()=>{
            // add the file to the array
            videos.push(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

    this.setState({
         videos: videos
    });
}
```

2. Your axios request should now looks like bellow

   axios.post(url, {
   videos: this.state.videos
   }).then(...);
3. After all, in your Laravel controller you'll have an array of data uri videos, so you must get each video data with the php function [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Example:

```
public function uploadVideos(Request $request){

    $videos = $request->input('videos');

    foreach($videos as $key => $v){

         // Get the video data
         $video = file_get_contents($v);
         // Save the video to the local Laravel disk
         Storage::disk('local')->put('name of the video', $video);

    }

}
```

**Note**
With this example you can upload multiple or single video files.

Hope this can help you.